# How to execute curl command using python 3.6 windows

Tags: python, windows

I have a curl command, Which works on my UNIX server.I want to execute it using python script.
curl comma:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1" -d '{"name":"Suppression_Testing","timeRange": {"startTimeMillis": "2017-12-25T04:16:30+0000","endTimeMillis": "2017-12-26T06:16:30+0000"},"affects": {"type": "APP"}}' --user api@adgm-nonprod:ac@123`

https://apcn.adm.com/controller/api/accounts/3/applications/61/actionsuppressions

I tried import os and executed curl butI am getting error as POST invalid syntax.
Also I tried using subprocess

`subprocess.Popen(curl 0)` but no luck. Can anyone help me?

Many Thanks,
Apurva Acharya

Comment: please share the code that you are trying with

Comment: Why would you use an external process for this? `requests` does everything `curl` does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python , subprocess module to do this

```
from subprocess import Popen
command='''curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1" -d '{"name":"Suppression_Testing","timeRange": {"startTimeMillis": "2017-12-25T04:16:30+0000","endTimeMillis": "2017-12-26T06:16:30+0000"},"affects": {"type": "APP"}}' --user api@adgm-nonprod:ac@123'''

#use shell=True , this will allow you to run the command in a single string on a shell like environment 

proc=Popen(command,shell=True)
```